# Cygwin - launch windows program without cygwin env vars

Tags: cygwin

I need to execute windows program over ssh. I have cygwin installed, ssh working but I've run into small issue. The program needs some environment variables which cygwin modifies (one of them is TERM). How can I launch the program with default set of windows environment variables?

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from creating a script which redefines the environment variables using the values you want?

Comment: not really. it would be inconvenient (managing env variables twice, once for cygwin and once for windows), but not impossible. I just have hard time believing there is not a way to do it without it.